# Variable used within its own initial value Swift 3

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift3

I try to convert my code to swift 3 an I have spent hours on the following error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Here's was my original code:

```
let data: AnyObject = user.object(forKey: "profilePicture")![0]
```

I looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D%20Type%20%22Any%22%20has%20no%20subscript%20members) but I'm still stuck. (I do programming as a hobby, I'm not a pro :/)

I've try that:

```
    let object = object.object(forKey: "profilePicture") as? NSDictionary
    let data: AnyObject = object![0] as AnyObject
```

But now I get this error:

> Variable used within its own initial value

Comment: instead of `let object = object.object(forKey: "profilePicture")` use `let object = user.object(forKey: "profilePicture")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second issue: Use **always** a different variable name as the method name, basically use more descriptive names than `object` anyway.

First issue: Tell the compiler the type of the value for `profilePicture`, apparently an array.

```
if let profilePictures = user["profilePicture"] as? [[String:Any]], !profilePictures.isEmpty {
   let data = profilePictures[0]
}
```

However, the array might contain `Data` objects, if so use

```
if let profilePictures = user["profilePicture"] as? [Data], !profilePictures.isEmpty  {
   let data = profilePictures[0]
}
```

Or – what the key implies – the value for `profilePicture` is a single object, who knows (but you ...)

And finally, as always, don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: Also, don't just use `profilePictures[0]`. Use `.first` instead, and unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer also optional bindings.